# recursive calls to ajax cause memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Does the following code logic cause the original call's stack frame to contain the memory from each subsequent call (causing excessive memory usage)?

```
function foo (arg) {
    bar(arg);
}

function bar (arg) {
  $.ajax({
     success: function (data) {
         if (data['result'] == 'continue') {
            bar(data['nextarg']);
         } else if (data['result'] == 'done') {
            alert('done!');
         }
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: at first glance, **no**, but probably depends on browser

Comment: Are you experiencing anything that makes you believe this is happening?

Comment: depends on till what level data[nextarg] returns continue...Your browser will make multiple network calls in that case and response may call same method in loop...you can do the same on server and return only the final response...right ? or you can do lazy loading, only when required. Do u really need to make same ajax call based on response ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the code below using memory recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257816/is-the-code-below-using-memory-recursively)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not recursive. `$.ajax` is asynchronous, so the stack pointer isn't waiting for `bar` to return.

Instead, `$.ajax` fires an asynchronous process, then continues until it hits either an explicit or implicit return. In your case, there is an implicit return at the end of `bar`.

Your function consumes no more memory than it should.

```
function bar (arg) {
  // calls $.ajax, which is async, so it fires "whenever"
  $.ajax({
    // when the ajax is complete/successful, this function is called
      success: function (data) {
         if (data['result'] == 'continue') {
            bar(data['nextarg']);
         } else if (data['result'] == 'done') {
            alert('done!');
         }
     }
  })
  // exits immediately after
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was curious to see if this was the case, so I tested it using a simplified version. The code below is an ajax call that binds calls to itself in its own success routine, printing the call stack each time. As it turns out, the call stack is the same each time, i.e. **no memory leak**.

I have a hunch that the fact that the call is asynchronous may come into play - i.e. there isn't actually any recursion since the success handler is called by the browser directly on the success of the AJAX call, not from within the last invocation of the function.

Here is the code I used to test the hypothesis:

```
var count = 0;

function bar() {
    $.ajax("/", {
        success: function () {
            count++;
            console.trace();
            if (count < 4) bar();
        }
    });
}

bar();
```

And here is a live JSFiddle that shows you that the call stack is exactly the same on each invocation: https://jsfiddle.net/dtrgak9o/

Comment: There is not actually any recursion here because `$.ajax()` is async so `bar()` is completely done executing before the `success` handler gets called.  That's why there's no stack build-up.  This has nothing to do with jQuery  being smart.  This is a plain Javascript thing when structured this way with an async callback.

Comment: @jfriend00 I had edited my question to add info about the asynchronous callback, but I forgot to remove the speculation about jQuery. Just edited that out, thanks.